# Images Along With Post Only Applying In Django Admin and Not Regular Form

Tags: python, django

Like the title says, I'm trying to create a social media app and my users can upload text to their websites. Currently I'm working on adding Image functionality. I can easily add this images in the Django admin page, but whenever I try to do it from the User's create post form, nothing shows up. Here's my post create form:

```
{% extends "social/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content4 %}
  <h1>Make Your Post</h1>
  <p>Write a post / Share an image</p>
  <br>
  <div class="container">
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form|crispy}}

      <button type="submit" name="button">Make Post</button>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock content4 %}
```

Here's my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Posts
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from .forms import NewUserForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import logout, authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts' : Posts.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'social/social.html', context)

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f"New Account Created: {username}")
            login(request, user)
            return redirect ("/social")
        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                print(form.error_messages[msg])
                messages.error(request, f"{msg}: {form.error_messages[msg]}")
                return render(request, 'social/register.html', {"form" : form})
    form = NewUserForm
    return render(request, 'social/register.html', {"form" : form})

def logout_request(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.info(request, "Logged out successfully!")
    return redirect('/social')


def login_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
                return redirect ('/social')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username and/or password.")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username and/or password.")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'social/login.html', {'form' : form})


class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Posts
    fields = ['post_title', 'post_text_content', 'post_image']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_author = self.request.user
        print(self.request.user)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.
class Posts(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length = 40, help_text = 'Enter post title')
    post_text_content = models.TextField(max_length = 1000)
    post_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add = False)
    #Make optional Image Field
    post_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images', blank = True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-post_date', 'post_title', 'post_author', 'post_text_content', 'post_image']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('social-home')
```

That's pretty much it. If you need any more code, please ask me.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: To be clear, when I add the images from the admin "create new post" it works, but when I add the image from the regular django form it does not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `form` tag in you HTML to upload files.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```